# How to check if training or test data is initialized?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the TensorFlow dataset API with the switching mechanic to switch between training and test set.

```
dataset_iter = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)

features, labels = dataset_iter.get_next()

train_init_op = dataset_iter.make_initializer(train_dataset)
test_init_op = dataset_iter.make_initializer(test_dataset)
```

`features` and `labels` is used for the graph, for example:

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(features, units=dataset.labels.shape[-1])
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)
```

For each epoch for testing and training the dataset is switched by calling the respective initializer (`train_init_op`, `test_init_op`).

Now I would like to use a dropout layer but I don't know how to determine how to check if for the current run the training or test set is initialized:

```
is_training = ???
net = tf.layers.dropout(net, rate=0.25, training=is_training)
```

*`is_training` needs to be a variable and should not be evaluated on graph building time. If should be evaluated on every run.*

**How to do this?** I don't want to redefine the graph for test or training.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I already came up with a solution:

```
is_training = tf.Variable(False, dtype=tf.bool)
train_init_op = tf.group(dataset_iter.make_initializer(train_dataset), tf.assign(is_training, True))
test_init_op = tf.group(dataset_iter.make_initializer(test_dataset), tf.assign(is_training, False))
```

I added an additional variable that tracks the state (training / testing).
This variable also gets called when the initializer is called and is set the the right value.

I hoped that there is a integrated / out of the box version of that.

If someone knows one such solution, please feel free to provide an addition answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can try `tf.control_dependencies` :

```
with tf.control_dependencies([train_init_op]):
    net = tf.layers.dropout(net, rate=0.25, training=True)
```

Comment: Do you see a way to confirm that this is actually working on run time? The idea seems clear. One major draw back seems to be that the run time increases drastically with this approach.

Comment: @Spen There seems to be no discussion or example that B will have an impact on time. `tf.control_dependencies` also has many applications in official code.

Comment: I will check it again tomorrow. Maybe I did something wrong.